# We are using ResilioSync on QNAP NAS and one of our NAS got hit by QLocker ransomware, what can we do?

Tags: virus, qnap

We got hit by the QNAP QLocker ransom ware on our NAS and it encrypted a lot of files (datasets) that we are sharing by ReslioSync.

Is there some way to restore the files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are quick enough to deal with it before the default ResilioSync archiving time of 30 days.
Any other sync that shares the same file will have the unencrypted file in i[ts Resilio .sync/Archive folder](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204754239-Using-Archive-for-file-versioning-and-restoring-deleted-files-).  You can simply copy the contents of Archive back to the top level, as long as you are OK with overwriting any file that may have been modified and stored in the archive as well.
If you want to get fancier, you can check the dates and you will see that QLocker encrypted most files within a short period.